# Boot Stuck After Update to 18.04 from 14.04

Tags: 14.04, boot, upgrade, 18.04

I recently tried to upgrade a machine from Ubuntu 14 to 18 via `dist-upgrade`. The update appeared to proceed without problems. However, after rebooting and choosing 'ubuntu' from grub the splash screen loads with the dots underneath but gets stuck (no progress or keyboard / mouse input) after each dot has flashed once.

I have tried pressing <kbd>ESC</kbd> to display the text interface while booting. This works sometimes if I press it quick enough but the text is often a little jumbled, although sometimes not. I have also tried turning off the splash from grub by pressing <kbd>e</kbd> and editing the options. This however just gave a blank screen. I also tried selecting the 14.04 option which is still in grub. This boots fine. Re-running `dist-upgrade` from 14.04 didn't work. I also tried boot-repair from 14.04 to see it if would help but it just renamed and reordered the grub entries to make the 14.04 option 'Ubuntu' and the Ubuntu 18 option 'Ubuntu 18.04'.

When the text interface does work it appears to get stuck either at the part where it is waiting for entropy or just after these lines:

```
[ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
NetworkManager-dispatcher.service
[ OK ] Started GNOME Display Manager.
gdm.service
_
```

Any ideas how to sort out this mess and get the 18.04 upgrade to boot?

Comment: Ubuntu 14.04 LTS should be upgraded to 16.04 LTS (via `do-release-upgrade`  which ensures packages are upgraded in the correct order), then a reboot  to get 16.04 LTS running, then a second upgrade to go to 18.04 LTS via a second `do-release-upgrade`.  This is the tested path.  If you skipped 16.04 LTS, and used debian's `dist-upgrade` after manually adjusting your sources - I'd recommend a re-install (without format, use something else & don't format your partitions. the last part of the install will try and restore you packages so your programs are installed).  Otherwise it's manual checks..

Comment: I didn't do any manual adjustment of sources. Just `dist-upgrade` which went straight to 18.04 all on by itself. I'd be happy to remove the failed 18.04 and try the other method but I do not know how to do this. Do I just remove a partition?

Comment: `sudo apt-get dist-upgrade` (or `sudo apt full-upgrade`) will not move you from one release (14.04 LTS) to another, it will just do an upgrade of more packages than `sudo apt-get upgrade` allows.  The only way dist-upgrade can change from one release (14.04 LTS) to any other releases is via a sources change (performed via `do-release-upgrade`).  Something doesn't add up in my books (or I don't understand anyway).  No you don't remove a partition; nor would I re-install, as if you only `sudo apt dist-upgrade` you'll be on 14.04 LTS.  Boot with a '1 nomodeset` (removing quiet splash) and lsb_r..

Comment: It appears as if it it has upgraded packages and added a grub entry in /userdata replacing the home directory. Hmm maybe I’ll just have to wipe the machine and fresh install.

Comment: Ok. Just managed to find all of the old home directory files. The paths have just been messed up so no data lost. Will back up everything again just to make sure and clean install.

Comment: `sudo apt upgrade` has a lot of limitations (for stability, to avoid need for reboot etc) where as dist-upgrade allows minor program version bumps, can require a reboot etc..  If you had a kernel upgrade installed (which occurs with dist-upgrade), it will perform a `update-grub` which scans your system for other OS, then writes a new `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` file - this maybe all that happened. Either way it cannot change your version unless you did something to make it.  Do you have a dual boot, with 18.04 or another GNU/Linux or your system?  Maybe the grub.cfg or /etc/fstab mounts wrong parts

Comment: No dual boot but I had the OS (mountpoint /) on one drive and /home on another. It would be nice to fix it but ultimately I think a clean install will be less of a headache.

Comment: I agree that a clean install will be less of a headache. Good luck :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am answering my own question in case others searching for a similar answer find this helpful.

I accidentally used the Debian `dist-upgrade` command instead of Ubuntu's `do-release-upgrade`. This upgraded packages beyond what `apt-get upgrade` allows and also moved my home folder from where it was on a separate drive to the drive with the OS. It also replaced the old home directory with grub boot files. **No data was lost. If anyone else makes this mistake, your files may have just moved.** You may be able to boot using a different grub entry and recover them or use a live CD.

My solution was ultimately to ensure I have a backup of everything and perform a clean install.

TLDR: Don't use `dist-upgrade`, use `do-release-upgrade`.